# How to delete a specific row from a table using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on this Angularjs table. When I delete a customer (clicking on remove) the specific customer goes away and that works fine :). But let's say I search for an specific customer like Alex typing Alex in the search box, then I want to delete it, but for some reason my removePerson function targets the first customer from the table. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong inside my removePerson funcion. Thanks a lot!!

and here's my code:

```
var App = angular.module('sortApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

App.controller('mainController', function($scope, $modal, $log, $filter) {

$scope.sortType     = 'id'; // set the default sort type
$scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
$scope.searchPerson  = '';     // set the default search/filter term

// Array - List of People   
$scope.People = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Mike', Lastname: 'White', age: 26 },
{ id: 2, name: 'Carl', Lastname: 'Barns', age: 41 },
{ id: 3, name: 'Deb', Lastname: 'McDonals',age: 78 },
{ id: 4, name: 'Tommy', Lastname: 'Humbs', age: 32 },
{ id: 5, name: 'Mary', Lastname: 'Browns', age: 18 },
{ id: 6, name: 'Alex', Lastname: 'Sams', age: 50 },
{ id: 7, name: 'Beto', Lastname: 'Burns', age: 27 }
];  
/*
This function adds a new customer
*/
$scope.addPerson = function(){
var customer = {
    name: $scope.name,
    Lastname: $scope.Lastname,
    age: $scope.age,
};

$scope.People.push(customer);
};
/*
This function removes a customer
*/
$scope.removePerson = function(index){

if(confirm("Are you sure to remove Customer")){
        $scope.People.splice(index, 1);
    }
 };  
 $scope.openPopupScreen = function() {

 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  template: '<div class="modal-header">   <a class="close" data- dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" style="margin:10px;color:black;font-size:35px;"></i></a><h1>Add Customer</h1></div><div class="modal-body">    <form >' +
    ' <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right ng-binding">NAME:</label><input style = "width:300px;"type="text" class="form-control ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="person.name"></br>' +
    ' <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right ng-binding">LASTNAME:</label><input style = "width:300px;" type="text" class="form-control ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="person.Lastname"></br>' +
    ' <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right ng-binding">AGE:</label><input style = "width:300px;" type="number"class="form-control ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="person.age"></br>' +
    ' <button id = "myid" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add()"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i>Add New Customer</button>' +
    '  <button type="reset" class="btn ">Clear</button>' +
    '<div ng-hide = "error_name_message" id="Error_Message_name">'+
    '<p>Please enter a name</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div ng-hide = "error_lastname_message" id="Error_Message_Lastname">'+
    '<p>Please enter a lastname</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div ng-hide = "error_age_message" id="Error_Message_Age">'+
    '<p>Please enter age</p>'+
  '</div>'+
    ' </form>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
    '  <a data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">close</a>' +
    '</div>',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
});
modalInstance.result.then(function (newPerson) {
  $scope.People.push(newPerson);
});
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
$scope.person = {name: '', Lastname: '', age: ''};
$scope.error_name_message = true;
$scope.error_lastname_message = true;
$scope.error_age_message = true;


$scope.ok = function() {
$modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};

$scope.cancel = function() {
$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

$scope.add = function() {
//Pass newPerson to caller from main controller
if($scope.person.name === ""){  

$scope.error_name_message= false;
  $("#Error_Message_name").show().delay(1900).fadeOut(900); // don't leave error on screen for long
}
else if($scope.person.Lastname === ""){  
  $scope.error_lastname_message = false;
  $("#Error_Message_Lastname").show().delay(1900).fadeOut(900); // don't leave error on screen for long
}
else if($scope.person.age === "" || $scope.person.age < 1){  
  $scope.error_age_message = false;
  $("#Error_Message_Age").show().delay(1900).fadeOut(900); // don't leave error on screen for long
}
else{
$modalInstance.close($scope.person);
}
};
};

});
```

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome, deleting works as intended.

Comment: yes it works, but if you search the customer from the search box and then try to delete it didn't work. Anyway I was able to solve the problem. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Apologies, I could have read the question a bit better.  Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are passing the index key of the array of displayed element that is not the same of the original array. You can fix this in different ways. The one proposed here should work. Hope it helps.

Change your removePerson function into this:

```
$scope.removePerson = function(index){
    if(confirm("Are you sure to remove Customer")){
        angular.forEach($scope.People, function(value, key) {
            if (value.id === index){
                $scope.People.splice(key, 1);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And pass the id of the Person to the function from your HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash-o" ng-click="removePerson(people.id)"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Daniele it works!! I have a quick question. I also need to be able to edit customers information. I'm trying to think of a way , but no progress so far :(. Any suggestions on how to accomplish that?

Comment: In the similar way as it's done in the removePerson function...
in the html do the ng-click="editPerson(people.id, newInputFormValue)".
newInputFormValue will be a model. The editPerson function will be similar to remove but without the confirm and instead of splicing the array. $scope.People[key].name = inputValue. Hopefully I haven't miss anything.

Comment: Thanks Daniele I'll give that a try!